# Calculating the scale value to transform an iframe to cover it's content in the viewport

Tags: css, iframe, scale, viewport, css-transforms

I'm trying to make the object-fit: cover (or background-size: cover if it were an image) using an iframe with a vimeo video. As vimeo adjusts the video size according to the iframe width/height/aspect-ratio I thought that using the `transform: scale` property could be achieved.

Right know I have this logic to scale an iframe with a vimeo video, in most of the cases does the job (covers the screen) but it's not perfect:

```
const w = window.innerWidth
const h = window.innerHeight
const ratioVideo = 640 / 360
const ratioScreen = w / h

const calculatedRatio = ratioVideo / ratioScreen
// minimum scale value
const minRatio = 1.45

scaleVideo = calculatedRatio > minRatio ? calculatedRatio : minRatio
```

And then I have:

```
<iframe :style="`transform:scale(${scaleVideo})`"..>
```

but it won't fill completely the viewport, expecially when the viewport ratio is < 1 (landscape with much more width than height)

How would be the right calculation (of the minimun scale transform value) for every resolution? I guess i have the separete the portrait/landscape but can't find the key

Any thoughts?

-EDIT-

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/toni-michel-caubet/pen/povZRqz) with my current code if it helps to understand (in vanilla js because i'm using vuejs in my environment)

-UPDATE-

This updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/toni-michel-caubet/pen/NWPEXEJ) almost achieves what i mean, but for reason i have to add a small percentage to the caculated ratio, I guess it's becuase the scroll bars or something? code preview:

```
let calculate = function () {
  const w = window.innerWidth
  const h = window.innerHeight
  const ratioVideo = 640 / 360
  const ratioScreen = w / h

  if (ratioScreen > ratioVideo) {
    calculatedRatio = ratioScreen / ratioVideo
  } else {
    calculatedRatio = ratioVideo / ratioScreen
  }

  /* a little % more */
  calculatedRatio = calculatedRatio * 1.07 
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--s', calculatedRatio);
}
```

Comment: you want to fill the viewport when its size is less than 640x360? And the ratio must be 16:9, right?

Comment: @fcalderan i want it to fit the screen allways, no matter what the resolution is. The iframe ratio is 640/340=1.777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove centering code from CSS, your demo works. [See this pen](https://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/KKwrxPx?editors=0111)

```css
    .video {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    :root {
      --s: 1;
    }

    .video__player {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      transform: scale(var(--s));
    }
```

```js
let calculate = function () {
  const w = window.innerWidth
  const h = window.innerHeight
  const ratioVideo = 640 / 360
  const ratioScreen = w / h

  const calculatedRatio = Math.max(ratioScreen, ratioVideo) / Math.min(ratioScreen, ratioVideo);

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--s', calculatedRatio);
  console.log(calculatedRatio)
}

calculate()
window.onresize = () => {
  calculate()
}
```

Explanation: your iframe is set at 100% width/height, meaning it's technically already centered to the viewport. When using `transform: scale` function without specifying `transform-origin`, default value will be 50% 50% meaning it will scale from center of that element and not top left corner.

Comment: Even that the centering using transform translates makes no sense to me (but i believe it) + 1 for the `Math.max` and `Math.min`. Clever

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I made a little demo that I hope explains it a bit better: https://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/MWYLrQz